# Conditional Formatting: How to change cell colour based on previous cell data

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I am looking for help to create a formula that will highlight a cell if the variance of that cell is greater than 3 from the previous cell.
I have found a formula that will highlight cells less than the previous cell =AND(D5<D16,ROW()<>1).
I wish to modify this so if the current cell has a variance of greater than 3 from previous cell that it will change to red colour.
Any help would be great. Thanks in advance

[image]
For example please see screenshot. Whn the data is entered for March it will look at Feb result and see that the variance is greater than 3% and then highlight in red. Similarly for results for Jun, Sep and Dec.
The production yeild cells have formula in them already to calculate the %yield in case this makes a difference.
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by previous cell ?

Comment: Hi PeterH, In the example if the yield data is entered for Feb at 95 and hen March data is entered at 91, I want 91 to highlight in red as it is greater than a 3% variance from the previous month. I hope that helps.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of how you have set up the rule in the rule manager.

Comment: Screenshot added with the rule and what is been highlighted. The cells in the first screenshot is what I am aiming for. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
=AND(ABS(D3-D2)>3,ROW()<>1)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. Unfortunately that doesnt seem to work.I tested it and there is no response to entering values less that are less than 3 from previous cell.

Comment: Your post said you wanted to determine if something is greater than 3 from the previous cell, not less than three. If you edit your post with screenshots of your data and how you have defined the rule (including the AppliesTo Range), we can resolve this.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I have added a screenshot to the original post and an example of what I need. I hope this helps make it clearer. I really appreciate the support and help.